# How to implement an option that inverts all selection in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a Select from `react-select` that's multi option, I want an option placed on top op the others that **invert selected options to unselected and vice versa**.

And when this 'Invert selection' option is selected don't show in grey into selected options preview.

I know that there's a second parameter to `onChange` prop that means the action, where I can see which option were selected or unelected, but I don't know how to properly manage the options.

How my Select component looks like:

[image: selectui]

Code:

```
<Select
    placeholder="Selecionar..."
    defaultValue={issuesTypes.results.map(
        (iT) =>
            selectedCategoryOptions.includes(iT.id) && {
                value: iT.id,
                label: iT.title,
            }
    )}
    isMulti
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
    onChange={(options, a) => {
        if (Array.isArray(options)) {
            setSelectedCategoryOptions(options.map((opt) => opt.value));
        }
    }}
    options={(() => {
        let aux = [];
        issuesTypes.results.map((iT) => {
            if (iT.isActive) {
                aux.push({
                    value: iT.id,
                    label: iT.title,
                });
            }
        });
        return aux;
    })()}
    components={{
        Option: DefaultInputOption,
    }}
/>;

const DefaultInputOption = ({
    getStyles,
    Icon,
    isDisabled,
    isFocused,
    isSelected,
    children,
    innerProps,
    ...rest
}) => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
    const onMouseDown = () => setIsActive(true);
    const onMouseUp = () => setIsActive(false);
    const onMouseLeave = () => setIsActive(false);

    // styles
    let bg = "transparent";
    if (isFocused) bg = "#eee";
    if (isActive) bg = "#B2D4FF";

    const style = {
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: bg,
        color: "inherit",
        display: "flex ",
    };

    // prop assignment
    const props = {
        ...innerProps,
        onMouseDown,
        onMouseUp,
        onMouseLeave,
        style,
    };

    return (
        <components.Option
            {...rest}
            isDisabled={isDisabled}
            isFocused={isFocused}
            isSelected={isSelected}
            getStyles={getStyles}
            innerProps={props}
        >
            <input type="checkbox" checked={isSelected} onChange={() => {}} />
            {children}
        </components.Option>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Inside components prop you can overwrite some components, just like I did with Option in the above question, so I created a MenuList wich is the dropdown menu and passed to components:

```
components={{
     Option: DefaultInputOption,
     MenuList: MenuList,
}}
```

MenuList:

```
const MenuList = (props) => {
    return (
        <components.MenuList {...props}>
            <div
                style={{
                    padding: "8px 12px",
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    borderBottom: "1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220)",
                }}
                onClick={async (e) => {
                    for (let i = 0; i < props.children.length; i++) {
                        let child = props.children[i];
                        await child.props.selectOption(child.props.data);
                    }
                }}
            >
                Invert selection
            </div>
            {props.children}
        </components.MenuList>
    );
};
```

As you can see it has a div with inner text "Invert Selection" and the magic is in the `onClick` function, calling `selectOption` will trigger the UI selection on inputs inside `DefaultInputOption` and the `onChange` inside `<Select />`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you want to do that.

But you could add a new function  and validate if the "invert selection" option is selected

```
const isInverted = () => ( selectedCategoryOptions.find( item => item.id = "invert-selection"))
```

and use that function for the default values. If it is selected, then you can change the validation there:

```
 defaultValue={issuesTypes.results.map(
    (iT) => {
                 isInverted() ?
                     !selectedCategoryOptions.includes(iT.id) && {
                         value: iT.id,
                         label: iT.title,
                     }
                 :
                     selectedCategoryOptions.includes(iT.id) && {
                         value: iT.id,
                         label: iT.title,
                     }
            }

        selectedCategoryOptions.includes(iT.id) && {
            value: iT.id,
            label: iT.title,
        }
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer, but it didn't solve my problem, I think the `defaultValue` props is only used when rendering the component, not to manage selection. And your defaultValue solution has semantics problems, but I got the idea, anyways, thanks